# Does PLM package (PGMM function) use Windmeijer-corrected cluster-robust errors?

Tags: r, standard-error, robust-standard-error, generalized-moments

I am performing a GMM analysis using the `pgmm function` in the `plm packag`e in R. I read a lot about different errors (nonrobust, cluster-robust, Windmeijer-corrected cluster-robust errors) and I wanted to know which of them is included in the PLM package (as the default version)?

How can I verify, which type of error was used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never done GMM before, so I might misread your question as I don't understand it's background fully, but a simple quick search shows that there are different functions, [vcovHC](https://rdrr.io/cran/plm/man/vcovHC.plm.html), [vcovNW](https://rdrr.io/cran/plm/man/vcovNW.html), [vcovDC](https://rdrr.io/cran/plm/man/vcovDC.html), [vcovBK](https://rdrr.io/cran/plm/man/vcovBK.html), and [vcovSCC](https://rdrr.io/cran/plm/man/vcovSCC.html),  that provide a bunch of different options for the method of estimation.

---

Note that R uses different functions depending on the object type that is passed to the function. The `vcovHC` function will be different when used with an object of the class `pgmm`

> ```
> ## S3 method for class 'plm'
> vcovHC(
>   x,
>   method = c("arellano", "white1", "white2"),
>   type = c("HC0", "sss", "HC1", "HC2", "HC3", "HC4"),
>   cluster = c("group", "time"),
>   ...
> )
>
> ## S3 method for class 'pcce'
> vcovHC(
>   x,
>   method = c("arellano", "white1", "white2"),
>   type = c("HC0", "sss", "HC1", "HC2", "HC3", "HC4"),
>   cluster = c("group", "time"),
>   ...
> )
>
> ## S3 method for class 'pgmm'
> vcovHC(x, ...)
> ```

and it uses the Windmeijer correction.

> A special procedure, proposed by Windmeijer (2005) for `pgmm` objects is provided.
>
> ...
>
> Weidmeijer, F. (2005) A finite sample correction for the variance of linear efficicent two--step GMM estimators, Journal of Econometrics, 126, pp.25--51.

(the quote contains a typo in spelling the name)

Comment: Thanks, that helped. However, I still need some help for my understanding: It said that Windmeijer (2005) is provided for pgmm objects, does that mean that the robust standard errors are already shown in my summary of outcomes OR do I still need to calculate them and then add them afterwards using vcovHC?

Comment: Good answer! Note that the type in the authors name (Weidmeijer instead of Windmeijer) is not present in current version of pkg `plm` but some websites having a copy of the old documentation have it.

Comment: When using the `summary` method for `pgmm`, argument `robust` default to `TRUE` and will give you the Windmeijer correction in summary's output.